# Django how to create forms with 'subforms'

Tags: django, forms, django-forms, django-crispy-forms, subforms

First of all, let me explain what I'm trying to achieve. I have a Django application which gets it's data from a third party source, so I can't use the default Django model classes or model form classes to start with. I have been using django-crispyforms for now to create my forms.

Let's say I have a 'Workflow' class which has a set of 'Workcenters' in it, and each Workcenter can have it's own set of Workunits. Each Workunit can be of a certain type ... whith every different Workunit type possible having additonal fields.

Now I've been asked to have a form where the user can change some general information about the 'Workcenter', but also change some data for each 'Workunit' in that Workcenter. Since in advance I have no idea how many Workunits are in the Workcenter, nor what type of Workunit it will be, it's very important that this form is built dynamically. Additionally they want each Workunit detail to be on a tab in a tab holder.

I have been able to generate a basic form with the tabs for each workcenter and within those tabs the necessary tabs for each workunit in the workcenter, but I seem to be stuck now...

Now my question is ... how should I approach this. Should I create layout's for every WorkunitType (using inheritance of course to inherit common parts), and add them in dynamically? Should I be using forms and some kind of sub forms?

For completeness sake ... This is what I have so far :

```
# Django Imports
from  django import forms
from  django.forms import CharField, Form, DateTimeField, PasswordInput, ChoiceField
from  django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

# Crispy Forms Imports
from  crispy_forms import layout
from  crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from  crispy_forms.bootstrap import Tab, TabHolder
from  crispy_forms.layout import LayoutObject, Layout

# Common Workflower Imports
from  common.forms import ReadOnlyFieldsMixin, SubmitCancelButtonsLayout, SubmitCancelFormActions
from  common.xeon import Panel

# Add your forms here

########################################################################
class WorkunitLayout(Layout):
    """ Base Workunit Layout ... every Workunit Type will have 
        it's own implementation of this Layout
    """
    workunitID = forms.CharField( label = 'ID' )
    wuType     = forms.CharField( label = 'Type' )

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.has_key( 'workunit' ):
            self.workunit = kwargs['workunit']

        super(WorkunitLayout, self).__init__(
            layout.Fieldset( 
                self.workunit.ID,
                layout.Field( 'workunitID'),
                layout.Field( 'wuType' ),
                layout.HTML('<p>Wat is dit?</p>'),
            ),
        )


########################################################################
class  WorkunitTab(Layout):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Constructor"""
        if kwargs.has_key( 'workunit' ):
            self.workunit = kwargs['workunit']

        super (WorkunitTab, self).__init__( 
            #WorkunitForm(),
            WorkunitLayout( workunit =  self.workunit ),
            #Tab( self.workunit.ID, WorkunitLayout( workunit =  self.workunit ) ),
        )

########################################################################
class WorkcentersTab(Layout):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #if kwargs.has_key( 'workflow' ):
            #self.workflow=initial['workflow']

        #if kwargs.has_key('workcenter'):
            #self.workcenter=kwargs['workcenter']
            #print "WorkcentersTab.workcenter={0}".format(self.workcenter)

        super(WorkcentersTab, self).__init__(
            TabHolder(
                Tab( 'Workunits' )
            ),
        )


########################################################################
class workflowForm(forms.Form):
    workflowID = forms.CharField(
        label=_('ID'),
        max_length=100,
    )    

    workflowType = forms.CharField(
        label=_('Type'),
        max_length=100,
        required=True,
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super (workflowForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.workflow    = self.initial['APIObject']
        self.workcenters = self.workflow.workcenters

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        #self.helper.layout = layout.Layout(
        myLayout = layout.Layout(
            Panel( 
                _('Productie Workflow'), 
                layout.Fieldset(
                    'Configuratie',
                    layout.Row(
                        layout.Field('workflowID', wrapper_class='col-sm-6'),
                        layout.Field('workflowType', wrapper_class='col-sm-6'),
                    ),
                ),
                TabHolder(
                    Tab('Workcenters' ),
                ),
                colored=True,
            ),
            SubmitCancelButtonsLayout(),
        )

        if ( self.workcenters <> {} ):
            print "workcenters={0}".format(self.workcenters)
            for name in self.workcenters:
                workcenter = self.workcenters[name]
                workcenterLayout = Tab(name, WorkcentersTab(workcenter=workcenter))
                print "workcenter[{0}]={1}".format(name, workcenter)
                ##print "workcenterLayout[{0}]={1}".format(name, workcenterLayout)
                if workcenter.workunits <> {} :
                    for workunitname in workcenter.workunits:
                        workunit = workcenter.workunits[workunitname]
                        workunitLayout = Tab(workunitname, WorkunitTab(workunit=workunit))
                        print "     workunit[{0}]={1}".format(workunitname, workunit)
                        workcenterLayout[0][0].append(workunitLayout)
                        ##print "     workunitLayout{0}={1}".format(workunitname, workunit)
                        ##workcenterLayout[1].append(workunitLayout)

                myLayout[0][1].append(workcenterLayout)

        self.helper.layout = myLayout
```

In fact ... my tabs are now dynamically created, the Fieldsets do appear in the tabs, the 'Wat is dit?' is there too, but the fields are not showing up. I've tried quite a few things already ... sadly without any luck so far.

Comment: If you want to add/delete form in django dynamically, you need django formset: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/formsets/. You might also want to take it easy on the frontend, so you can use https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset.

Comment: Even with a formset I have to know in advance how many 'subforms' to add and which specific ones ... or am I mistaken ?

Comment: The good thing about formset is that you don't need to specify how many, as long as you defined the formset then django would automatically split your `POST` data into a list of forms. You might need to search form some examples online but once you know it, it should make sense.

Comment: What I mean is I would have to create a formset and include the actual workunitform for each workunit (based on it's type), and that is something I don't know and will only know at runtime.

Comment: In my case WorkUnit 1 could require a 'Press' form, WorkUnit 2 could require a 'Bind' form, WorkUnit 3 a 'Cut' form ... or any other combination which I don't know ... and will only know at runtime.

Comment: Sounds like you need formset for each of those types. But if the types are a lot, it might cause issues with your UX. I couldn't find a better solution, hope that helps.

Comment: @ShangWang well ... if only I could find a good example. Only examples I seem to find is for formsets which have X amount of forms of one single type :-(